# How do I install Adobe Dreamweaver on Ubuntu 14.04 with Wine?

Tags: wine, ubuntu-14.04, dreamweaver

I am trying to install Adobe Dreamweaver CS4 using Wine on Ubuntu. Google searches have resulted in tutorials for old versions of Ubuntu, Wine, etc. I need a solid way to install and run Adobe Dreamweaver CS4. If any files need to be copied, I have an existing Windows installation. I am looking for a step-by-step guide.

How do I install Adobe Dreamweaver on Ubuntu 14.04 with Wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [Successfully running Dreamweaver CS6 with Wine](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2160653) describes the process for
Ubuntu 10.04 and Dreamweaver CS6, but should still work for your versions.
If you encounter any problems, please post them, but first have a look at this article :
[WineHQ - Adobe Photoshop CS2](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2631).

The described procedure transplants an existing Dreamweaver installation
on Windows into Wine.

> Successfully running Dreamweaver CS6 with Wine this evening, after
>   piecing together information from the following pages:
>
> http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20236&iTestingId=53581
>   http://www.thetechrepo.com/id=567
>   http://blog.int3ractive.com/2010/08/how-to-run-flash-cs5-on-ubuntu-with.html
>
> I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid), but will try upgrading to
>   12.04.2 next.
>
> I copied EVERYTHING Adobe from a Windows 7 machine into the relevant
>   location(s) in the `.wine/drive_c/` folder:
>
> ```
> C:/Program Files (386)/Adobe/              *See note
> C:/Program Files (386)/Common Files/Adobe/ *See note
> C:/Users/Andy/AppData/Local/Adobe/
> C:/Users/Andy/AppData/LocalLow/Adobe/
> C:/Users/Andy/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/
> ```
>
> *Note: I had to rename the "Program Files (386)" folder to "Program Files" for a 32bit only installation of Ubuntu. I can't comment on
>   64bit versions, only that to make sure you get the directory names and
>   structure correct.
>
> Then I exported everything Adobe from the registry:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Adobe   HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Adobe
>   HKEY_USERS/S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx/Software/Adobe
>
> I'm not sure if ALL those registry entries are needed, but I thought
>   better safe than sorry, and left nothing to chance! I renamed the
>   exported .REG files to adobe1.reg, adobe2.reg, and adobe3.reg for
>   simplicity, and put them in the /home/ folder, then ran the following
>   commands in Terminal:
>
> ```
> wine regedit adobe1.reg
> wine regedit adobe2.reg
> wine regedit adobe3.reg
> ```
>
> Open Winetricks and choose "Select the default wineprefix" and click
>   next. Then "Install a Windows DLL or component". I installed the
>   following (again, probably overkill!):
>
> ```
> atmlib
> gdiplus
> msxml3
> vcrun2005
> vcrun2008
> vcrun2010
> ```
>
> Next go back to the selection screen, and choose "install fonts":
>
> ```
> corefonts
> tahoma
> lucinda
> uff
> ```
>
> With all that done, I simply went to the Dreamweaver installation
>   folder, right-clicked on Dreamweaver.exe and chose "Open with Wine
>   Windows Program Loader", and it fired right up!
>
> Hope this helps someone.
>
> Incidentally, I also copied all the files for Photoshop CS6 and
>   Illustrator CS6 at the same time, but neither worked. They crash
>   whilst initializing.

Comment: 64bit versions?

Comment: Just replace in the above `Program Files (386)` by `Program Files`.